# Convergence in distribution vs convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $ X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n} $ be i.i.d. with mean $ \mu $ and variance $ \sigma^{2} $. Then $ \bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} $ converges in distribution to $ N(0, \sigma^{2}/n) $ and $\bar X$ converges in probability to $\mu$. We also have that $ \sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu) $ converges in distribution to $ N(0, \sigma^{2}) $. But I have been told, that also $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} $$ will converge in distribution to $ N(0, \sigma^{2}) $. I dont think this is true since for example the mean will grow without bound as $ n $ tends to infinity. Is this true ?

I know, that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution. So how SHOULD I interpret $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} $ ? As convergence in probability, convergence in distribution or none of the aforementioned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to say that
$$
\bar X=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i
$$
converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma^2/n)$. The variance cannot depend on $n$. However, by the law of large numbers $\bar X$ converges to the expected value $\mu$ in probability and even almost surely.

The sequence
$$
\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i
$$
indeed does not converge to $N(0,\sigma^2)$ because the expected value gets bigger and bigger unless the expected value is equal to $0$. We have to center the variables to obtain convergence, i.e.
$$
\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)=\sqrt n(\bar X-\mu)
$$
converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I hope this helps.